# Has the double slit experiment been conducted with electrons in a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

The double slit experiment is an example of electrons behaving as waves.

I know that this experiment has been performed with only single electrons being propelled at the slits, and that the result of this has still been wave behavior. This is most often explained by stating that the electrons travel through both slits.

Has this experiment been performed in a vacuum? Can the wave behavior possibly be explained by a single electron creating a wave front made of multiple electrons?

Comment: The accelerated electron produces synchrotron radiation (photons) that radiate spherically in the shape of a wave. That could be a wave front that spreads through both openings.

Comment: Even in vacuum we kn0w that particles and anti-particles p0p int0 existence and annihilate. This c0uld explain the interference pattern if it interferes with the electr0n. And as I believe there is n0 such thing as empty space. Gravity warps space, well y0u can't warp n0thing. It c0uld be that the very substance 0f spacetime causes interference.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, all experiments involving electron beam are performed under vacuum to avoid losses due to collisions with background molecules.

It is for instance the case of the celebrated double slit experiment performed with electrons by Akira Tonomura et al in 1987 (http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.16104).

Answer (score 2):

The experiments are under vacuum as it is not possible to manipulate single electrons in non-vacuum, as Penangol has answered.

The answer to

> Can the wave behavior possibly be explained by a single electron creating a wave front made of multiple electrons?

is NO, due to charge and electron number conservation.

In general statements like :

> This is most often explained by stating that the electrons travel through both slits.

Are imposing classical framework logic to a quantum mechanical phenomenon. Quantum mechanical phenomena can only be described by probabilities of interaction, in the case of the double slit, the probability of passing through one or another slit. Probabilities are accumulated measurements which show the interference. The individual electron on the screen is whole, within the impact point.

Answer (score -4):

The wave behavior is produced by a single electron and a vacuum does not affect it. In my opinion I believe the accelerated electron produces synchrotron radiation (photons) that radiate spherically through both slits. This could guide the electron like a pilot wave.